# Difference between <compilation debug="true"> and .csproj file settings?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, web-config

Setting `<compilation debug="true/false">` in Web.config seems to do things that you can also set in Visual Studio in Project properties, Build tab. Are they connected somehow? Does one of them takes precedence when compiling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not connected. The compilation tag is ASP.NET only, while the project option one is for Windows Forms, console, WPF and so on.

ASP.NET compilation is so special, so you have to dive further to learn about every piece of it,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178466.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging symbols into the compiled page. Because this affects performance, set this value to true only during development.

Comment: I know what happens when I set the attribute, as I wrote I want to know if there is a connection between it and the seemingly similar features of the Project Properties in Visual Studio.