# asp.net webconfig Debug=true and Solution Configuration as Debug

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, debug-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between <compilation debug=“true”> and .csproj file settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934570/difference-between-compilation-debug-true-and-csproj-file-settings)

In an ASP.net web application, you have two 'debug' settings.  One is in the webconfig itself, and the other is when actually compiling the solution in Visual Studio.  First of all, are these related?

An issue we have normally when compiling in Visual Studio as 'Release' is that when trying to diagnose an error via a stack trace / log files:

1. Line numbers do not match
2. Sometimes, line numbers are not even shown

This is very problematic for troubleshooting applications on live environments, and is almost a deal-breaker for me.

What is the difference between setting debug=true in webconfig, and compiling in Debug mode, and can you set debug=false in web.config, while compiling in Debug mode?

Comment: They aren't connected; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934570/difference-between-compilation-debug-true-and-csproj-file-settings for more information. The key thing is that ASP.Net compiles on the first request, so this is when the debug=true config option comes into play. It can also be made to be pre-compiled via the aspnet_precompile tool, but both these activities are outside of Visual Studio.

Comment: There are more factors involved (running with(out) Debugger). But what is your main question? Fix the stacktraces?